# Can Testflight public links set for an internal build or it has to be reviewed first for external use?

Tags: iphone, testflight

When you submit a build to Testflight its immediately available for use by internal testers, if you want to make it available for external testers then it can sometimes take several hours before Apple process it and make it available for external testers (and they can reject it at this stage).

If I want to make a build available to a 3rd party and time is of the essence and don't want to wait for the Apple processing time can I create a public link for them as soon as the build has been uploaded to Testflight?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is only possible to share a build with a third party on testflight after it has been approved by Apple. However, if you have an external testing group, you should be able to add this build to the group (and add the person you want to share it with). Then, a link to download the beta app will be sent to that person as soon as the build is approved. That is the quickest way.

Comment: I hope this answers your question.